# TypeError: Cannot read property 'rarity' of null at Promise.all.inventory.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Line 132 of code:-

> ```
>               if (!item.rarity) {
>                 const rarity = (
>                   tags.find((t) => t.category === 'Rarity') || {}
>                 ).name
>
>                 updateQuery = { ...updateQuery, rarity }
>               }
> ```

Output:-

> (node:58908) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use
>   updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead. (node:58908)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'rarity' of null
>       at Promise.all.inventory.map (C:\protect1\utilities\inventoryFetch.js:132:29)
>       at  (node:58908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
>   inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
>   promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: No, we don't know how to fix it, you've given far too less context. Line 132 of what? How are you calling this code? What is `item` expected to be?

Comment: @Bergi I’m sorry, will update post when I got back home.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'item' is getting a value of undefined at this point of the code.

Since it's in a function that returns a Promise, and you clearly haven't handled the error case through catch() block, this error is popping up.

Log the item variable just before the if-else block.

Put a catch() block wherever you are using this function and log the error there itself.